# Render value to blade view in Laravel

Tags: laravel, data-binding, laravel-blade

I have this query in Laravel

```
$total_mess = Chat::whereRaw('to_user = ? and view = ? ', [Auth::user()->username, 0])->count();
```

I want to pass this value to the `menu.blade.php` file.The `menu.blade.php` file I'm using for multiple view(in index page,details page .....).

So how can I do achieve that.

Kind regard.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass globally

```
\View::share('total_mess', $total_mess);
```

Comment: i use the AppServiceProvider.php and [here](http://prntscr.com/abjzok) is my code. I encounter errors Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found .I have try to modified to path but still not working .Any suggest about this

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view composer and this view composer will be called everytime the view is rendered.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers

```
public function boot()
    {
        // Using class based composers...
        view()->composer(
            'profile', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer'
        );

        // Using Closure based composers...
        view()->composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
            //
        });
    }
```